# Javascript JSON parse and stringify for multi levels

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript object that contains a property with values of another json stringified object. I cannot get the printout version of the string back to object form. See the following code. the `console.log` output content of `json` string is exactly as right side of `jsonFromStr`. However, `JSON.parse(json)` is OK, while `JSON.parse(jsonFromStr)` is error. What is wrong here?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jma7889/qtmmpj2t/

```
level2Obj = { key2a: "foo", key2b: 3};
level2ObjJson = JSON.stringify(level2Obj);
level1Obj = {key1a: "bar", key1b: {level2ObjJson}};

json = JSON.stringify(level1Obj);
jsonFromStr = '{"key1a":"bar","key1b":{"level2ObjJson":"{\"key2a\":\"foo\",\"key2b\":3}"}}'; // same than json

objFromStrify = JSON.parse(json); // OK
objFromAssignedString = JSON.parse(jsonFromStr); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this it will work:

```
jsonFromStr = '{"key1a":"bar","key1b":{"level2ObjJson":"{\\\"key2a\\\":\\\"foo\\\",\\\"key2b\\\":3}"}}';
```

The reason that your version does not work is that the escape sequence `\"` is resolved at that very moment, and so the actual value of `jsonFromStr` will be:

```
'{"key1a":"bar","key1b":{"level2ObjJson":"{"key2a":"foo","key2b":3}"}}'
```

... which is invalid JSON.

You need to keep those escapes unresolved in the JSON string, and this you do by escaping the escape sequence itself with additional slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonFromStr = '{"key1a":"bar","key1b":{"level2ObjJson":{\"key2a\":\"foo\",\"key2b\":3}}}';
```

You have an extra "" for value of **level2ObjJson** key,replace **jsonFromStr**  in your code with the above code .